# Issue getting PHP to accept checkbox selections

Tags: php, html

I am trying to get PHP to accept the information from a series of checkboxes in a form but when I try to verify/use said data to manipulate other data it isn't there.

```
<p><input type="checkbox" name="toppings[]" value="xchese"/>Extra Cheese</p>
<p><input type="checkbox" name="toppings[]" value="xmeat"/>Extra Meat</p>
<p><input type="checkbox" name="toppings[]" value="veg"/>Vegetarian</p>
```

```
if (isset($_POST["toppings"]))
{
    $toppings = $_POST["toppings"];
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($_POST["toppings"]); $i++)
    {
        printf("<p>Topping %s</p>", $_POST["toppings"][$i]);
        if ($toppings[$i] == "xchese")
        {
            $sando_total += 1.50;
            printf("<p>Extra Cheese</p>");
        }
        else if ($toppings[$i] == "xmeat")
        {
            $sando_total += 2.00;
            printf("<p>Extra Meat</p>");
        }
        else if ($toppings[$i] == "veg")
        {
            $sando_total += 2.00;
            printf("<p>Vegetarian</p>");
        }
    }
}
```

Main issue happening in the for loop. It detects how many are being checked but not what the values are.

Comment: Get in the habit of using `foreach` to loop through an array, it makes the code easier to read and write.

Comment: I don't understand the question. Why doesn't it detect what the values are? That's what it's testing in the `if` statements.

Comment: Show us what you get from `var_dump($toppings);`

Comment: https://html.form.guide/php-form/php-form-checkbox/ might help. I am busy reading it now!

Comment: I agree with Paulo Santos: *It worked on my machine*...

Comment: Your code works fine. What is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

First I'd use [filter_input()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php) to filter the input correctly and initialize $sando_total. And as already mentioned above use a foreach-loop:

```
<?php
    
$sando_total = 0;
$toppings    = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "toppings", FILTER_DEFAULT, FILTER_REQUIRE_ARRAY);

if (!empty($toppings)) {
    foreach ($toppings as $item) {
        printf("<p>Topping %s</p>", $item);
        if ($item == "xchese") {
            $sando_total += 1.50;
            printf("<p>Extra Cheese</p>");
        } else if ($item == "xmeat") {
            $sando_total += 2.00;
            printf("<p>Extra Meat</p>");
        } else if ($item == "veg") {
            $sando_total += 2.00;
            printf("<p>Vegetarian</p>");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

First of all, ditch the brackets on the checkboxes name tag. They are not needed.

If you change the `method` tag of the `form` element to `GET` you'll see that the checkboxes in the form are "posted" as :

```
page.php?toppings=xchese&toppings=xmeat&toppings=veg
```

In any case, iterating through the `$_POST["toppings"]` should be sufficient.

As we usually say in software development: *It worked on my machine.*

Comment: If you remove the `[]`, `$_POST` will only include 1 value for `toppings`.  Likewise in `$_GET` - if you checked your example you'll see only the last value is available, as each overwrites the last.